# Which rules for logarithms do I miss out on?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In my math book there is this equation:

$$b^{\log_{b}{(u)}}=u$$

I do not understand how the left side equates the right side. Which laws and rules do I miss , may somebody explain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is just the definition of logarithm.

Comment: It's the very definition of logarithm. $\log_b u = k$ means that $k$ is the value so that $b^k =u$ (assuming there is a unique such value; i.e that $b > 0$ and $b \ne 1$).  So by definition:   $\log_b u=k\iff b^k=u$ so $b^{\log_b u} = b^k = u$.  That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that by [definition of logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) with $u>0$ and $b>0,\neq 1$ we have

$$v=\log_b u \iff b^v=u$$

therefore by definition

$$ b^{\log_b u}=b^v=u$$

As a concrete simple example, we have that

$$\log_2 8 =3$$

then

$$2^{\log_2 8}=2^3=8$$

Comment: I love concrete examples... as many as possible. :-)

Comment: @JohnJoy In a simple case like that, I think it can be importantto clarify better the idea for the equivalence.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $b >0; b\ne 1$ then $\log_b u$ is, by definition, $\text{"whatever power we must raise b to in order to get u"}$.

So $b^{\log_b u} = b^{\text{"whatever power we must raise b to in order to get u"}}=\text{b raised to a power that gives us u as a result}= \text{u as a result} = u$

In other words.... It's just the definition of logarithm.

Comment: That's exactly the point! It seems a simple fact, and it is indeed, but I think that often some time is necessary to digest the notations.

Comment: But you need to know what things mean and their *meanings* determine a lot of aspects about them.  For example $\frac ab\times b = a$.  Why? What rule tells us that.  Well, by definition $\frac ab$ means "the value when multiplied by $b$ will give us $a"$.  So $\frac ab\times b$ means "the value that when multiplied by $b$ will give us $a$, mulitiplied by $b$".  If it gives us $a$ when multiplied by $b$ and we *DID* mulitply it by $b$, the answer is $a$.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes we find it useful to express a given positive number as a power of some fixed positive number different from $1,$ usually called a base. Then if I expressed $u>0$ as a power of $1\ne b>0,$ then I have something like $$u=b^{\ell}.$$ This $\ell$ is what's called the logarithm of the number $u$ to the base $b,$ or for short, we say that $\ell=\log_bu.$ Thus, we may truthfully write that $$u=b^{\log_bu}.$$

Comment: $\ell$ is  avery good choice as exponent!